# Combining multiple likert scale variables into a new, single variable

Tags: spss, data-transformation, likert

I am attempting to combine Likert scale variables into a new variable using SPSS. One of my new variables would combine 3 items that are scaled 1 to 5 with 1 = strongly agree and 5 = strongly disagree. A 4th item to be included to create the new variable is scaled 1 = friendly to 7 = unfriendly.

How do I create the new variable? Do I use the means of each of the questions, or do I use a median of the 4 or 7 response levels.

Comment: Sorry if this is too late, but, have you tried doing FA, so that at least you can reduce 5the number and simplify the problem?

Comment: One of the better ways to achieve this would be to do factor analysis on the individual items and, if the unifactorial solution shows good fit, use factor scores from that solution as your composite variable. It's not ideal, but it is better than simply averaging across categorical items.